# Prevent Android from killing SQLite CLI when executing a long-running query

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

As part of a little benchmarking I'm doing for an app, I'm opening an `adb shell`, running the SQLite command line interface (`sqlite3`), and executing a long-running query to see how it performs on the device's hardware, with the installed version of SQLite.

However, SQLite keeps exiting, bringing me back to the ADB shell.  The only message that's displayed is "Killed".  Since I've seen SQLite report sepecific errors like "out of memory" before, I assume Android is killing the process, as opposed to SQLite encountering a problem.  Assuming that is the case, is there a way to prevent the system from doing so?

I was hoping that if a watchdog process was killing the process for being non-responsive or taking up too much CPU time for too long, [`stop`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#othershellcommands) might help but it didn't.

This is roughly what I'm doing when my process gets killed, shortened up a bit for this post:

```
$ adb shell
root@android:/ # cd /database/location/
root@android:/database/location # sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> .output /dev/null
sqlite> .timer ON
sqlite> SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;
Killed
root@android:/database/location #
```

Comment: What is the query? SQLite version?

Comment: @CL. The SQLite version is 3.7.11. The query is... a bit much to post but it's sound. It runs as expected on my desktop (using the same 1.1 GB database) and it runs on the Android device when using a smaller data set.

Comment: @user1147688 Sorry, no updates.  I think Android is killing the process and there's nothing that can be configured easily to prevent that.

Comment: What do you get in logcat?

Comment: @user1147688 Nothing.  I don't believe the sqlite executable does any logging to LogCat and I didn't see anything relevant, where Android logs that it's killing the process, for example.

Comment: You can try: `setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog V` and `setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements V` to see extra SQLite log info... Also make sure you use *logcat* with the `*:V` flag to get verbose messages.

Comment: @user1147688  If an error is happening in SQLite, I would expect that to be logged a little prominently than the "verbose" logging level.  But I don't think SQLite was encountering an error executing the script.  Instead, I speculate that Android was killing the process because of excessive CPU usage, memory usage and/or execution time.  It's been a long time since I was doing that work though.  If you are encountering a similar issue, feel free to experiment and report back whatever you find.